# Magento 2 : How to use message manager without block in phtml file

Tags: magento2, frontend

I want to use message manager in template file without using block/controller.

I want to send error message on `/customer/account/index/` when redirect here. I redirect it from registration template file.

How to do it..?

I used this type of code but it's not working...

```
$this->_messageManager->addError(__("Error"));
$redirect->setRedirect($this->getBaseUrl().'customer/account');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use of direct object manager in template file is not proper way to do a coding. Use always __construct() method defined in block or controller and get object from them.**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$messageManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface')
$messageManager->addError(__("Error"));
```

Comment: but I override phtml file... and use core block of magento. Then how to pass message when redirect?